# user authentication not working on mongodb 3.6.5

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have installed mongodb 3.6.5 on aws ec2 server and setup following in .conf file

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: serverIP

security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

then created user with following command in admin db and restarted mongodb

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "mydbuser",
    pwd: "mydbpass",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

now when I try to access db from console with following command if doesnt allow me and gives me error of authentication.

```
mongo serverIP --port 27017 -u "mydbuser" -p "mydbpass" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Can someone help me what is wrong with it.

getting following error

```
MongoDB server version: 3.6.5
2019-01-11T08:46:50.245+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

Comment: show the error message

Comment: @right update question with error response

Answer (score 0):

The method you are following is correct but there is some variations in mongodb while accepting credentials as string. You might need to enclose your username and password within single quote instead of double quote as follows.

```
mongo serverIP --port 27017 -u 'mydbuser' -p 'mydbpass' --authenticationDatabase 'admin'
```

Double quotes will work if you dont have special characters in your username/password.

For more details on mongo Check here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/